# ios application is not launching after updating xcode from 4.3 to 5.0.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5.1

I have updated xcode from version 4.3 to 5.0.2. 
Before updating I was able to debug application on device running ios 5.1.
Now when I run application using device, It only display splash screen and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method does not call so it gets stuck on splash screen.

Note: when I unplug cable and then launch manually then it runs perfectly as it should.

Is there any problem with my configuration?

Comment: You can look at the logs that were recorded when the app crashed by plugging it back into your Mac, opening Xcode, going to the Organizer (`CMD+SHIFT+2`) and looking at the Console for your device. Hopefully here you should be able to see what's causing the crash.

Comment: Hung in debugger or failed to attach to process happens all the time..

Comment: ya it happens same problem m also facing. can you reach to solution?

Comment: set you debugger to `GDB`.

Comment: I have seen the console I got this Error>: 01737000 load_application_info: Could not load signer identity from /private/var/mobile/Applications/06EAFFF1-88AC-41FE-94E6-5AC4F5CEE824/ .. DO I need to delete profile and again install provisioning profile again?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Change your app Debugger at **edit scheme > debugger** to GDB (<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the panel).
2. Reset your simulator or delete app from device.
3. Run new fresh version of your app.

This works for me, hope it works for you also.

Comment: GDB is not in there. There is only one option which is LLDB , Do I need to install debugger ?

Comment: application is launching using LLDB debugger but it is terribly slow. I waited for one minute then the application launched and first interaction was too slow then application became completely responsive. can anyone identify the problem?